# Observing controller property (participating in queryparam) from service without observer

Tags: ember.js, observable

I moved state properties from controller to service except queryParams. now I would like to have one of the query param property to service.
Is there any way to achieve this without using observer ?.

I am currently doing it using observer.

**controllers/application.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
const {computed,observer} = Ember;
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  myService:Ember.inject.service(),
  appName: 'Ember Twiddle',
  changedAppName:observer('appName',function(){
    this.get('myService').changeAppName(this.get('appName'));
  }),
  actions:{
    changeApp(){
      this.set('appName','NewEmberApp');
    }
  }
});
```

**templates/application.hbs**

```
<h1>Welcome to {{myService.appName}}</h1>
<br>
<button {{action "changeApp"}}>Change</button>
<br>
{{outlet}}
<br>
<br>
```

**services/my-service.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Service.extend({
  appName:'SSS',
  changeAppName(param){
    this.set('appName',param);
  }
});
```

[EmberTwiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/68d59ce5a4293d6f90112de6d9a13805?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need the observer at all? Just set the appName of the service directly inside your changeApp action of the controller:    `this.set('myService.appName','Kumkanillam');`
 and remove the observer completely.

Your question became sth. different after your comment. Let me clarify if I understand your question correctly with the following [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/1fe2f599e300aacf7028f35aad1eb9ab?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs). In that case; you are modifying appName both at controller and component; which is an illustration of violation of DDAU principle. In this situation you need observer inside the controller in order to be notified about appName change at component level.

In order to solve this problem; you can create an aliased computed property at controller level and pass it to component (or other components or route templates) and you will get rid of the observer. This [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/ce41cbd25e2e8d5d0285af00a04ecb15?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C) explains what I mean.

Even if what I understood is correct and what I provided might be a valid answer; do not forget that violating DDAU will hurt you at some point and you are going to have to refactor your code in future. Hope this helps.

Comment: I am aware of setting service properties from controller. many of the places I am changing appName property, to avoid repeated code of setting service property I require some mechanism that will automatically take care of the associating appName controller property to service.Currently I have not followed DDAU principle so this property might be changed in many other places...

Comment: I have modified the answer after reading your comment; since your problem is different from what I understood at the begining.

Comment: So i should not change `appName` directly in controller, I should always come through services. am I right ?

Comment: IMHO, only the owner of the data should modify it. In your case; if the appName belongs to the controller; only the controller should change it.  If it belongs to the service; it should only be changed through service's public interface. In the first twiddle I have provided; appName is modified in two places (controller & component); so we needed observer. I prefer to provide common functionality through services and store application-wise cross cutting data inside services. So claiming that nothing should be changed in controllers and every change should go through services is too ambitious.